present statement for a past event
I bought a tree then gave it to my boss  and said to him "It is the best tree they had in the shop".
I think it is weird  because the statement   is in present  for a past event , would it be better to write
It was the best tree they had in the shop or it was the best tree they had when I visited the shop.
What do you think ?

Both are possible, when the relevant statement is still valid.
I think "was" is more idiomatic, and we tend to use "is" to draw attention to the continuing validity of the statement.

so there no mismatch with "is " ?

@YvesLefol - It was the best tree they had in the shop, and it still is.

@YvesLefol - it was, is, and always will be the best tree they had at the time you visited the shop.
